# Sorting Columns With BlueprintJS Table

Tags: html, css-tables, blueprint, blueprintjs

I want to be able to sort my column based on ascending or descending numbers. I don't totally understand the way to do this. The online documentation shows that a Menu must be added to the table, but how does the menu know to affect which column.

This is the current way I have my BluePrintJS table implemented. I want to make the values sortable ascending or descending for any column

```
<Table enableFocusedCell="true" numRows=10 class="bp3-html-table bp3-table-resize-horizontal">

            <Column
              columnHeaderCellRenderer={() => (
                <ColumnHeaderCell name="Name" />
              )}
              cellRenderer={i => (array.data[i] ? (<Cell>{array.data[i].name}</Cell>)
                : (<Cell />))
            }
            />
            <Column
              columnHeaderCellRenderer={() => (
                <ColumnHeaderCell name="Ins" />
              )}
              cellRenderer={i => (array.data[i] ? (<Cell>{array.data[i].ins}</Cell>
              ) : (<Cell />))
            }
            />
</Table>
```

Comment: It seems like you're going after the blueprint table features example. Take a look at the source code for it: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/cf1ea5d26f840cbcf44ffda15012e57fe899b1b7/packages/docs-app/src/examples/table-examples/tableSortableExample.tsx

You'll see that it's quite involved but if you break it down, I think it'll be clear how to make it work.